# Gibberish in MATLAB (SSI file), Command not showing (MAT file)

Tags: matlab, mat, ssi

[I tried to open a SSI file from 2007 in MATLAB, but i can only see gibberish in the command window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giHMB.png)

[also tried using the MAT file, yet there is nothing in the command window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irJV9.png)

Both of them used the same data, just in different format, I need either one of them for my project to generate a 3D graph, can someone teach me how to fix this issue?

Thanks!

I have tried fopen, disp for the mat file, but nothing shows up.

Comment: The “gibberish” you see is the binary file opened as a text file in the editor. Yo I didn’t try to load the data. When you used `load` you did it right, the data loaded. You don’t need to see anything. Type `whos` to see a list of variables defined in the workspace, which are the ones you loaded from the MAT-file.

Comment: Actually on the right pane you have a list of variables in the workspace, you can see your loaded data there.

Comment: Thanks! I am searching for the command from my professor's work actually, I am trying to get hints to generate the 3D figure based on his work, but I couldn't load any commands, as all the commands is gibberish when i open the SSI file

Comment: I have no idea what an SSI file is, but it looks like a plain MAT-file. It wouldn’t have commands in it, just data.

Answer (score 0):

after you load the MAT-file in the command line, the data saved in it will appear on the workspace panel. Hence, the next step is to use these data to the desired task, for instance generating a 3D graph. From the second pic you give, there are 2 variables (*a* and *t*) have dimensions equal in row numbers. after you get the variables from the MAT-file, you can use `plot3` command to generate 3D graph.